# when I change admin URL, my project API URL not found. how can I solve it?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, cookiecutter-django

when I change the  URL link
`path("admin/", admin.site.urls),`
to
`path("", admin.site.urls),`  it works fine

but raises API Not Found Error when I have the following urlpatterns.

I need `path("api/", include("config.api_router")),`

Note: when I use   `path("admin/", admin.site.urls),` API  works

Comment: can you post `config.api_router` urlpatterns'
i guess you might need `path("api/", include("config.api_router.urls"))`

Answer (score 1):

Django [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher) *runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL*. Try switching the order:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("api/", include("config.api_router")),
    # other urls
    path("", admin.site.urls)
]
```

Comment: That's what I wanted. But here it gives an error API does not get root